# Error en swirl (): no se pudo encontrar la función "swirl"

Tags: rstudio

Por que cuando al ejecutar el comando `>swirl()` en `RSstudio` me aparece un mensaje de Error

> in swirl() : could not find function "swirl"

¿Aún cuando ya está instalado? lo que hice fue volver a instalarlo e instalar todos los paquetes y lecciones que iba a usar y funcionó, pero al salir de `swirl` y querer entrar de nuevo me aparece ese error de nuevo, utilizo Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que activar la librería ya que cuando cierras R se cierran todas las librerías para no hacer pesado el programa es decir debes escribir:

`>library(swirl)`

`>swirl()`